# twillio phone number lookup sdk5x

Tags: php, twilio-api

Twillio returns a object which has allot of private properties when looking up a phone number. Right below is the code i use

```
function isValidNumber($number) {
    try{
        $obj = $this->client->lookups->phoneNumbers($number)->fetch();
        return $obj;
    }catch(Twilio\Exceptions\RestException $e){
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is a fragment of result that i'm getting

```
object(Twilio\Rest\Lookups\V1\PhoneNumberInstance)#23 (4) {
  ["properties":protected]=>
  array(6) {
    ["callerName"]=>
    NULL
    ["countryCode"]=>
    string(2) "LK"
    ["phoneNumber"]=>
    string(12) "+94xxxxxxxx"
    ["nationalFormat"]=>
    string(12) "xxxxxxxxxx"
    ["carrier"]=>
    NULL
    ["addOns"]=>
    NULL
  }
  ["solution":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    ["phoneNumber"]=>
    string(11) "94xxxxxxxxx"
  }
}
```

is there a elegant way to get the **phoneNumber** key out ? Also the try catch doesn't seem to help either, as soon as an invalid entry goes in, exceptions are all over the place. I'm using the SDK 5x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is stuck due to lack of examples and not that much helpful documentation, I came up with something really simple. This is not elegant at all but for now gets the job done

```
file_get_contents('https://'.$sid.':'.$auth_token.'@lookups.twilio.com/v1/PhoneNumbers/'.urlencode($number));
```

Comment: PS - cURL is the way to go, if for some reason you are left out without cURL, this actually works.